# UIDevice systemVersion sometimes contains the OS name

Tags: iphone, ios, version

I have a problem with the method [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]. We have a report with devices using the app, and sometimes we get a string like "iPhone OS 6.1.3".

I don't know if there is another property for getting just the number (6.1.3) or if I have to implement a method to remove the first part.

Also I don't know exactly how many type of strings can I receive from several devices.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a regular expression to grab solely the number.

some simple expression like `\b[0-9].[0-9](.[0-9])?\b` or something like that.

This can be applied through an `NSRegularExpression`.

Something like this

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\b[0-9].[0-9](.[0-9])?\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *version = [[expression matchesInString:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try with that. Anyway I didn't find why this function returns different string formats, I don't know if this depends on the device, OS, or something else.

Comment: I have no idea, but it is almost always better to be safe than sorry by doing something simple like this.

Comment: I have edited my solution to correct the regular expression string. I made a mistake in it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with several options and it works with this one: @"([0-9].[0-9].?[0-9]?)".

Comment: What is there currently should work and make sure there is not a hanging period or that string in the middle of a word, etc. Just for a more solid validation though the method `systemVersion` shouldn't return anything weird or malformed

Comment: Period or dot in standard regular expresion syntax means any single character so you should escape the dots; probably should also group the second and third version segments because they might not be there.

Comment: I haven't test this, but it should work: @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*"